# saving text data from UITextField without pressing additional key (help needed)

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am new to iPhone programming. I am working with UITextField and UITextFieldDelegate. I have five textfields. I am trying to input data in them using numberPad keyboard. And the data should be 1 digit long. After that hitting another key should take it to the next textField. I have implemented it all but the only problem is when all 5 textfields are filled, I have to press keyboard 6th time to save the text data of fifth textField, Is there any way I could save the text data of 5th textfield without pressing any key on the keyboard 6th time?

Any help or suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks
Vik

Comment: Can the user randomly select which text field he wants to enter first? I am guessing this works similar to sites where we input or credit card numbers 4 digits at a time. :-)

Comment: @Praveen - Well user can select click on any textField but according to my code, the control would go to the first TextField but after that user can randomly select any textfield. any ideas how to implement it?

Comment: @Praveen - Thats right and I tried it but the thing is UITextField Methods are not initiated until i hit another key on number pad keyboard while im in textfield5 ( which i don't want). I want to press a key which will resign textField4 and the result will give me stored numbers from all textFields from 1 to 4 plus the key pressed to resign textField 4 and entering TextField 5. Is there any way for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use textFieldDidChange delegate Method for 5th TextField and compare it like this.

if (textField==textField5 && [textField length]>0){

[textField resignFirstResponder];

}

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thats right and I tried it but the thing is UITextField Methods are not initiated until i hit another key on number pad keyboard while im in textfield5 ( which i don't want). I want to press  a key which will resign textField4 and the result will give me stored numbers from all textFields from 1 to 4 plus the key pressed to resign textField 4 and entering TextField 5. Is there any way for that?

Comment: I think you can do all the logic in this method. You just need to check for which textField you are in. That's it. That is why I compared it with TextField5 so it will do nothing if any other textField. You can check other TextField here as well in switch case. Perhaps you can share some code so can get exact idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming that you are using UITextFieldDelegate method to move to next text field. You can keep a count on how many text fields are entered and keep checking it:

```
if(count == num_of_textfields)
{
  [textField resignFirstResponder];

  //Call your method to process the input here.

}
```

Comment: @Matteo - Thats right and I tried it but the thing is UITextField Methods are not initiated until i hit another key on number pad keyboard while im in textfield5 ( which i don't want). I want to press  a key which will resign textField4 and the result will give me stored numbers from all textFields from 1 to 4 plus the key pressed to resign textField 4 and entering TextField 5. Is there any way for that?